# ActiveMQ Artemis REST integration throwing exception

Tags: rest, activemq-artemis

I am trying to REST interface to the ActiveMQ Artemis 2.13.0 by building integrated REST war file and copying the war file to "apache-artemis-2.13.0\web" and starting service.

To configure I have followed [this documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/1.0.0/rest.html).

Getting exception

```
2020-12-07 16:47:11,894 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221013: Using NIO Journal
2020-12-07 16:47:11,933 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221057: Global Max Size is being adjusted to 1/2 of the JVM max size (-Xmx). being defined as 477,364,224
2020-12-07 16:47:11,952 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224097: Failed to start server: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.protocol.ProtocolManagerFactory: org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocol.amqp.broker.ProtonProtocolManagerFactory not a subtype
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:590) [java.base:]
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1237)
```

and

```
2020-12-07 16:47:12,077 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.rest] AMQ182004: REST configuration parameter consumer-window-size' is deprecated. Use 'url' instead.
2020-12-07 16:47:12,409 WARN  [org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext] Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@6b9c42bd{/artemis-rest-1.0,file:///D:/ABroker2.13.0/tmp/jetty-localhost-8161-artemis-rest-1_0_war-_artemis-rest-1_0-any-9922358792097605704.dir/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{D:\apache-artemis-2.13.0-bin\apache-artemis-2.13.0\web\artemis-rest-1.0.war}: java.lang.RuntimeException: ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.rest.integration.RestMessagingBootstrapListener.contextInitialized(RestMessagingBootstrapListener.java:54) [artemis-rest-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
```

I have referred old post regarding the similar issue, but didn't resolve my issue.

My `pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.github.jdanekrh</groupId>
    <artifactId>artemis-rest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
           <artifactId>tjws</artifactId>
           <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
           <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>artemis-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>artemis-jms-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>artemis-core-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>artemis-commons</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq.rest</groupId>
            <artifactId>artemis-rest</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And `web.xml`:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
        "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>

  <context-param>
        <param-name>rest.messaging.config.file</param-name>
        <param-value>rest.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
  

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- this commented out section is the only difference from the embedded config -->

    <!--<listener>-->
      <!--<listener-class>-->
         <!--org.apache.activemq.artemis.rest.integration.ActiveMQBootstrapListener-->
      <!--</listener-class>-->
   <!--</listener>-->

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.apache.activemq.artemis.rest.integration.RestMessagingBootstrapListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>Rest-Messaging</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.FilterDispatcher
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Rest-Messaging</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    
</web-app>
```

Can some one help me if I am missing anything?

Comment: If required I will share pom.xml and web.xml

Comment: Please share your `pom.xml` and `web.xml`. Also, please elaborate as to why you're using REST. Generally speaking STOMP is recommended over REST since it's typically a much better option.

Comment: Why are you using the documentation from ActiveMQ Artemis 1.0.0 when you're using 2.13.0? Have you tried using the latest release (i.e. 2.16.0)?

Comment: We are using REST over STOMP(Note: earlier we were using AMQP for both publish and consume).

Comment: We are new to this ActiveMQ. We were implemented both producer and consumer using QPID AMQP libraries. Our producer applications is in 1000-10000 number reporting single Artemis server and connection stayed persistent. So we received feedback from ActiveMQ Artemis consultant that exposing ActiveMQ Artemis is not good practice and suggested to expose REST API.

Comment: [pom.xml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GGj0_72dbgOWHnoTVWWNbPoy38mMSLRh/view?usp=sharing)
[web.xml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15ac3ObRUv65QkpEIVqmWjma0nefGokq9/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Who was the ActiveMQ Artemis consultant? I'm puzzled why they would recommend using REST over AMQP. AMQP is a superior protocol in every way. Can you elaborate on exactly why they recommended using REST over AMQP? I don't know what you mean by "exposing ActiveMQ Artemis is not good practice."

Comment: Our use case is, to make persistent connection with on ActiveMQ Artemis server.(i.e. 10000 sensor : 1 Artemis server)

Comment: As per the suggestion:

- Using AMQP, one of the problem we run into managing the connections come and go it is hard to get lot of insight into what's going on the broker. So it is challenging to manage and troubleshoot.
- broker aren't built with the intension of serving very large numbers of endpoints
they built with the intension of moving messages quickly between endpoints.

Rest:
The tooling which are available in HTTP, and for scaling and for frontend and it is really for superior to broker itself.

Comment: It's not clear why the broker would struggle to handle 10,000 AMQP connections but then magically handle 10,000 HTTP connections without any problems. I would recommend against using the REST interface for this. Also, you say your use-case involves "persistent" connections. How is that different from just a normal connection?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply, Our requirement is, sensors (client which connect to Artemis server) in concurrent way we are using AMQP acceptor in broker
We would like to know:
1. What would be maximum concurrent connection could be handled by Artemis broker (includes both publisher and subscriber)
2. Does broker connection has any dependency with acceptor (STOMP, AMQP, HTTP etc...)

Comment: "It's not clear why the broker would struggle to handle 10,000 AMQP connections but then magically handle 10,000 HTTP connections without any problems".     to answer this - All the client application connecting to HTTP server(Integrated with REST interface) Rest interface creating single connection with Artemis broker. Example using AMQP 100 Client creates 100 Connection @Artemis broker but using Rest interface 100 HTTP client creates 100 Connection in HTTP server and 1 Connection in Artemis broker.

Comment: I see two potentially significant problems with that approach - performance and security. Perhaps you should start a thread about this on the [ActiveMQ user mailing list](http://activemq.apache.org/contact/#mailing) or even join the [ActiveMQ Channel on ASF Slack](http://activemq.apache.org/contact/#chat) for further discussion. Comments on Stack Overflow really aren't the place for this.

Comment: I have posted my query in ActiveMQ user list [link](https://markmail.org/message/cbpeumtqy3cpsnlp)

Answer (score 0):

You wrote about setting at web.xml

```
<param-value>rest.xml</param-value>
```

1. Make sure that your integrated REST war file really includes ***/WEB-IBF/classes/rest.xml***
2. Make sure that it contains setting

> ```
> <rest-messaging>
>    ...
>    <url>tcp://localhost:61616</url>
> </rest-messaging>
> ```

Documentation specifies *vm://0* instead, but in my view this does not work or demands some custom (non-default) configuration for emdedded broker.